# search regex pattern and python function needed

Tags: python, regex

I have file which the following statements.

```
start < some 50 words > End          //need to work only on these types
start < some 50 words >
start < some 50 words > End
start < some 50 words > 
< some 50 words > End
```

...This pattern is repeated 10000 times.
I want to replace the lines which has 'start' in the begining and 'End' in the end with

```
start2 <same 50 words > End2.
```

I need to keep the same words in between just modify the start and end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

data = """start < some 50 words > End
start < some 50 words >
start < some 50 words > End
start < some 50 words >
< some 50 words > End
"""

print re.sub('start(.*)End', 'start2\g<1>End.', data)
```

prints:

```
start2 < some 50 words > End.
start < some 50 words >
start2 < some 50 words > End.
start < some 50 words >
< some 50 words > End
```

Comment: This \g<1> is new to me.Can you give me details as to what is this.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It's just a way of referring to a saved group, in this case to `(.*)`.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are more work than you need to go to for this problem -- it can all be done more simply with plain old string methods:

```
def ReplaceStartEnd(s):
...    if s.startswith("start") and s.endswith("End"):
...       return "start2" + s[5:-3] + "End2"
...    else:
...       return s
```